# how to recognize the font style and size of the doc file in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

I'm developing one special job portal website in `asp.net`. Here I want to display the resume (`.doc` file) preview and some content in that resume is display into textboxes.

Here my problem is, can I find the content depending on the font style and font size on the resume?

please answer anyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use OpenXMl SDK tool. it gives you the doc as xml files and every paragragh has it's properties include the font name and size. for example:

```
    <w:p w:rsidR="00941A8B" w:rsidP="00941A8B" w:rsidRDefault="00941A8B" xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main">
      <w:pPr>
         <w:jc w:val="center" />
         <w:rPr>
           <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:cs="Arial" />
           <w:sz w:val="24" />
           <w:szCs w:val="24" />
           <w:rtl />
        </w:rPr>
      </w:pPr>
   </w:p>
```

you have to read more about it. you can see more info [Here](http://www.notesfor.net/post/2009/09/16/Add-and-update-custom-document-properties-in-a-docx-.aspx).
I'm sorry I can't give you specific code how to do it but I can say that you **Can** do it by this tool

Comment: hi , sorry.. i didnt understand. what i am asking is , how can i find the data in the file (.doc or .docx) depending on the font style and font size?